# user Management

Tags: authentication

I am planning to build a website. Not sure what technology going to use, but most likely ruby or php. We are not going to use any CMS, so everything can be customized easily. The only question is: If we do not have a CMS, is there any scripts/libraries/etc available out there for user management like: asp.net membership, that can be easily added to a website, so there will be different levels of users, and admin panel also.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to try Python, you might take a look at [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/). It includes a nice [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) authentication and authorization system integrated with the framework. See the [book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08) for details. If you have any questions, you'll get lots of help from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

web2py is very easy to set up, learn, and use. You can [download](http://web2py.com/examples/default/download) it and start playing with the scaffolding app within a couple minutes (requires no installation or configuration, and has no dependencies -- even runs off a thumb drive).

Answer (score 0):

They all have something like this. It's a basic part of a web framework. Choose a language/framework first and then come to this hurdle.